# Some % of Order Emails don't get sent

Tags: magento-1.8, transactional-mail

I see quite a few questions about emails not being sent, I think what I'm experiencing is somewhat different than the majority of the problems out there.

Typically my transactional emails (orders, invoices, shipments) are successfully sent but some % of them never get sent.  I've noticed that with both automatically generated emails and also manually 'resent' emails from admin interface.  Sometimes I have to manually resend multiple times.

My practice is to BCC all outgoing emails to an email account so I have a record of exactly what emails are sent.   But a good % of transactional emails are never received by customer or my BCC account.

I don't see any relevant errors in logs, Magento or PHP.   Any suggestions for tracking this down?

Answer (score 0):

Known issue, in your Sales Emails setup on **Send Order Email Copy Method** use **Separate Email** instead of **BCC**

Comment: So a random % of the emails fail because of using BCC ?